# Cocos2D-JS can't load json file exported from CocosStudio

Tags: javascript, json, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-js, cocos2d-html5

I'm trying to load a json file exported from cocosstudio v2.3.2

```
var myScene = ccs.sceneReader.createNodeWithSceneFile('res/Scene.json');
```

I got this code from `sample-cocos2d-js-scene-gui-master` 
The problem is, i get this error: `Can't find the parser : undefined` 
 
How do i fix this issue? 
I'm very new to using javascript and I hope someone can help me with this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to use `ccs.load("")` It's new api. This function returns table `{node, action}` node it's your scene "node" and "action" it's a time line action it's optional.
Your code would look like this:

```
var sceneRes = ccs.load("res/Scene.json");
this.addChild(sceneRes.node);
```

And if you want use the action, just run it for node.

```
sceneRes.node.runAction(sceneRes.action);
sceneRes.action.gotoFrameAndPlay(0, true);
```

Hope this help, and sorry for my english

Comment: it worked! i wish i could up vote your answer 1million times. Thank you!