# Cocos2d js: load scene from json

Tags: cocos2d-js

I'm trying to understand how to make Cocos Studio exported scenes run inside cocos2d js project. seems like there is no documentation at all.
I tried to instantiate scene object in different ways

```
var scene = ccs.csLoader.createNode("res/MainScene.json");
// or
var scene = cc.load("res/MainScene.json");

//res/MainScene.json is declared in resources 100%
```

but scene variable always contains empty objects (node and action).
I debugged `load` and `createNode` methods with step into feature and found that there is no proper parsers for scene. 
I've stuck and don't know where to go next.

Does anyone know for sure if Cocos Studio is compatible with Cocos 2d JS?

UPDATE
here is the code I'm using to initialise the project

```
cc.game.onStart = function(){
    cc.view.enableRetina(cc.sys.os === cc.sys.OS_IOS ? true : false);
    cc.view.adjustViewPort(true);
    cc.view.setDesignResolutionSize(960, 640, cc.ResolutionPolicy.SHOW_ALL);
resolution size
    cc.view.resizeWithBrowserSize(true);
    cc.LoaderScene.preload(g_resources, function () {
        var scene = ccs.load("res/MainScene.json");
        cc.director.runScene(scene.node);
    }, this);
};
cc.game.run();
```

it's autogenerated by setup.py script, I just replaced Scene creation code with load from json. 
after var scene =  line of code scene object is null or undefined

Comment: Cocos changed api. Look my answer in this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35035027/cocos2d-js-cant-load-json-file-exported-from-cocosstudio/35054806#35054806)

Comment: Hi Dazlonar, I saw your answer, unfortunately it didn't help, I suspect I'm doing something absolutely wrong. could you please see my updated question?

Comment: ok, I think, I found the reason, the question you linked was helpful from this perspective. I found that JSON scene object structure generated by Cocos Studio I currently have doesn't match json mentioned in question you attached. It's crazy, why is it happening?

Comment: may be it's due to cocos engine version? however, I downloaded latest version 3.10 and the result is the same

Comment: I think i understand why you have a problem. You don't add "res/MainScene.json" to g_resources list in resource.js

Comment: Find "resource.js" in project folder and add "res/MainScene.json" to res - var res = { HelloWorld_png : "res/HelloWorld.png", MainScene : "res/MainScene.json" }; It's needed to download your file

Comment: Oh, you wrote "res/MainScene.json is declared in resources 100%". I miss this. If is true, i don't understand why its happens, maybe you using old cocos studio file provided as cocos sample. Try to create new CocosStudio project.